# Unable to use sudo command because pam_open_session module is unknown

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, ubuntu-18.04, pam

*It is showing.......*

**sudo: pam_open_session: Module is unknown
sudo: policy plugin failed session initialization**

**I can use pkexec command but sudo isn't running. Can anyone help me?**

My pam.config file looks like

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# /etc/pam.conf                                  #
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#
# NOTE
# ----
#
# NOTE: Most program use a file under the /etc/pam.d/ directory to setup their
# PAM service modules. This file is used only if that directory does not exist.
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------#

# Format:
# serv. module     ctrl       module [path] ...[args..]          #
# name  type       flag                              #
```

My pam.d/sudo file looks like

```
#%PAM-1.0

session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale user_readenv=0
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
session required /home/iknownothing/simple-pam/mypam.so
```

Comment: This is usually a question for the Linux and Unix, and not too much to do with programming. However, `PAM` is a linux builtin, `sudo` is an extension. Can you add your PAM config / sudo config?

Comment: I got my answer actually, I added the last line in pam.d/sudo which causing my sudo to not work, after removing it using pkexec permission in vim, it starts working normally!!!!!